Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoAsset'
I upgraded to Expo Sdk 51. Since the update, I have been getting this error. I tried npx expo install expo-asset. But it didn't work. What could possibly be the error here?
I tried npx expo start. My React Native code works on expo go, but crashes when I use a development build.
Also I tried XCode Archive, but the app crashes upon loading everytime.
I tried rm -rf node_modules and yarn install, but still got no luck

I am having a similar issue, yet not the same exactly, but Expo Assets and version 51 are involved.
Have you tried npx expo-doctor and npx expo install --check ?
Feel free to share more details about the errors you get

Yes, I have tried both. But nothing is fixing the error.

this fixed my issue

yeah! npx expo-doctor has downgraded two libs and now it's working!

The latest version of expo-asset isn't compatible with expo SDK 51. I downgraded the version to 8.11.0 and it worked.
Also somehow, writing use_expo_modules! in my Podfile, did the trick for me.

In xcode => Build Phases => Compile Sources, check if the ExpoModulesProvider.swift file has been added.
In my case, I use a bare React native installation

Tu é um Deus! (You are a God).
Thanks!

I had the same problem and fixed it by rebuilding my project with

eas build --profile development --platform ios,

then, after reinstalling the build on my device,

npx expo prebuild
cd ios
pod install
npx expo run:ios

For me, it was also necessary to run npx expo-doctor and remove problematic dependencies.
Good luck!

Using expo to install expo-crypto worked for me
expo install expo-crypto
